# How taxing are loops in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm learning about the custom painter in Flutter and have been working on creating a compass which I can animate. The way I have gone about it is to use a loop to spit out x,y offset coordinates as you can see in the code below. I am running the code block 3 times, one with 360 cycles (1 deg), one with 16 cycles (22.5 deg) and one with 4 cycles (90 deg). When I render the custom painter in debug mode, I don't have an issue with performance but I'm wondering what other peoples opinions are. Would creating an image like this then animating it be too taxing on the computer?

```
class Compass extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paintStrokeThin = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 1.0
      ..color = Colors.black;
    final paintStrokeNormal = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 2.5
      ..color = Colors.black;
    final paintStrokeThick = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 3.0
      ..color = Colors.black;
    createCompass(
      outerDistanceFromEdge: 10.0,
      innerDistanceFromEdge: 15.0,
      noOfPoints: 360,
      paint: paintStrokeThin,
      size: size,
      canvas: canvas,
    );
    createCompass(
      outerDistanceFromEdge: 5.0,
      innerDistanceFromEdge: 15.0,
      noOfPoints: 16,
      paint: paintStrokeNormal,
      size: size,
      canvas: canvas,
    );
    createCompass(
      outerDistanceFromEdge: 0.0,
      innerDistanceFromEdge: 15.0,
      noOfPoints: 4,
      paint: paintStrokeThick,
      size: size,
      canvas: canvas,
    );
  }

  void createCompass(
      {double outerDistanceFromEdge,
      double innerDistanceFromEdge,
      int noOfPoints,
      Paint paint,
      Canvas canvas,
      Size size}) {
    final _width = size.width;
    final _height = size.height;
    final _interval = (360 / noOfPoints) * (pi / 180);

    for (var i = 1; i <= noOfPoints; i++) {
      var rad = i * _interval;
      var x1 = (0.5 * _width - outerDistanceFromEdge) * sin(rad) + 0.5 * _width;
      var x2 =
          (0.5 * _width - innerDistanceFromEdge) * sin(rad) + 0.5 * _height;
      var y1 =
          (0.5 * _height - outerDistanceFromEdge) * cos(rad) + 0.5 * _width;
      var y2 =
          (0.5 * _height - innerDistanceFromEdge) * cos(rad) + 0.5 * _height;
      canvas.drawLine(Offset(x1, y1), Offset(x2, y2), paint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(Compass oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Comment: On the computer or on the mobile devices?

Comment: I'm running this on desktop so it's also responsive.

Comment: tried using `Canvas#drawPicture`?

Comment: No I haven't tried with using drawPicture, I'll give it a go now.

Comment: @Levy77 it may be responsive on your desktop, but it may not run as well on others desktop, check my answer below and I highly recommend you watch the entire video :)

Answer (score 0):

Like any programming language, loops are expensive functions to [call](https://dev.to/benhayehudi/a-slow-death-by-for-loops-1004), especially when rendering on the UI (animations, widgets, etc). I suggest you open up your performance overlay and check how expensive rendering that widget is.

A simple but **KEY** rule is to **MINIMISE THE USE OF EXPENSIVE WIDGETS**, so consider if it is really necessary to run the code block 3 times or to animate.
Check out this long but important [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vVg9It7cOfY&t=52s) from the fluter team.

Finally, as you asked for opinions *complex animations for production apps is* **NOT** a great idea, especially if you are working alone!